# Is Wifi order printer available in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, order-email, print

Is there any paid/unpaid extension to print order automatically that are sent to my email : print@example.com via wifi/gprs printer ?

Also extension that supports wireless printers , suggestions required .

Comment: This seems like the wrong tool for the job. Why would you want magento to handle printing from an email? There are programs out there that can take all new emails in an inbox and send them to a networked printer, but that sort of thing being done from php sounds unnecessarily complicated, I suggest you consider an alternate route.

Comment: give me some suggestion in domain of php

Comment: PHP Isn't going to provide native interfaces to access wireless interfaces and printers in a simple way, why do you want this in PHP so bad

Comment: ok than suggest me some that programs who can done this job easily

Comment: [This one](http://www.namtuk.com/auto_email_manager.aspx) works